# UISlider Constraints Programmatically: "Constraint items must each be an instance of UIView or subclass"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uislider

My constraints are causing my app to crash due to them not being an instance of UIView. However, they *are* instances of UIView, at least to my knowledge. My goal is to attach this slider to the toolbar as a UIBarbuttonItem. Here is what I have in viewDidLoad:

```
// Slider Implementation
slider_textSize.minimumValue = 9;
slider_textSize.maximumValue = 72;
slider_textSize.value = 12;
slider_textSize.continuous = YES;

[self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.view addSubview:self.slider_textSize];

self.slider_textSize.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                          constraintWithItem:self.slider_textSize
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                          toItem:self.view
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                          multiplier:1
                          constant:5]];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint
                          constraintWithItem:self.slider_textSize
                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                          toItem:button_done attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                          multiplier:1
                          constant:10]];
```

"slider_textSize" is a strong, nonatomic property of this class and implemented in my initializer like so:

```
[slider_textSize addTarget:self
                 action:@selector(slider_textSizeValueChanged:)
                 forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

I've been using the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21810358/add-uislider-with-autolayout-programmatically) question, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. This is the error I get exactly:

```
2015-03-06 10:26:08.300 rED[14238:3168995] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: Constraint items must each be an instance of UIView or subclass'
```

I've tried everything I could with no luck. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `button_done`? Are you sure it is a `UIButton`?

Comment: Assuming `button_done` is a `UIBarButtonItem`, `UIBarButtonItem` is not a subclass of UIView.

Comment: button_done is a UIBarButtonItem that is also declared in my header. Sorry about that.

Comment: @dan ah ok that makes more sense. I tried adding it as a subview of UIView the same way I did for the slider, but it throws an exception any ideas on making it work with constraints?

Comment: Are you trying to add your slider to the toolbar? If so, you should create a bar button item from your slider using `[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:slider_textSize]` and add it as an item on your toolbar.

Comment: @dan I do this later when a specific button is pressed, which overrides the current toolbar array with the one from this code. Regardless, the code in the question above. Heres that specific buttons action code: `UIBarButtonItem *slider_ConvertedForBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:slider_textSize];
    
    NSArray *array_SliderInterface = @[slider_ConvertedForBarButton, flexibleSpace, button_done];
    [self.navigationController.toolbar setItems:array_SliderInterface animated:YES];`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I ended up ditching the constraints since they became too complicated with bar button items. Instead, I made the width of the slider a proportion to the width of the screen.

```
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

    CGFloat sliderWidth = .786 * screenWidth;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, sliderWidth, 32);
    slider_textSize = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

Comment: But did you a actually get to know the reason of error?